# R - Dplyr on a List of Columns

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I `merge` two data frames and then want to compare all of `.x` columns to all the `.y` columns to ensure they are same. I left a reproducible code sample below with an input example and what the desired out put would be. You can see I am using `dplyr` to `select`, `mutate`, and `filter` for each column comparison and then `rbind` together to get one `df`.

I would like to be able to use some sort of `grep` to call all the columns with `.x` and `.y` and then `sapply` to loop over all of them. Is there any way to do this more elegantly?

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(FoundOn = letters[1:10], ItemId = 1:10,
                 Brand = rep(c("Nike", "UnderArmor"), 5),
                 Product = rep(c("shoes", "shorts", "hat", "shirt", "pants"),2),
                 color.x = c(rep(c("red", "green", "blue"), 3), "red"),
                 color.y = c(rep(c("blue", "green", "red", "red"), 2), "blue", "green"),
                 price.x = rep(c(100,50, 25, 60, 80), 2),
                 price.y = rep(c(125,50, 30, 60, 80), 2))

ColorCheck <- df %>%
  select(FoundOn, ItemId, Brand, Product, color.x, color.y) %>%
  mutate(Check = color.x == color.y, CheckFrom = "ColorCheck") %>%
  filter(Check == F)

PriceCheck <- df %>%
  select(FoundOn, ItemId, Brand, Product, price.x, price.y) %>%
  mutate(Check = price.x == price.y, CheckFrom = "PriceCheck") %>%
  filter(Check == F)

#desired output:
Checks <- rbind(ColorCheck %>% rename(From.x = color.x, From.y = color.y),
                PriceCheck %>% rename(From.x = price.x, From.y = price.y))
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry! i think you called me out last time @MrFlick! I will work on my question representation. I am working on adding example. thanks.

Comment: i have updated with example.